# Structures and Split

Tags: vb.net

I am having difficulty with my vb program as my structure array will not fill with data from a text file which has been split using the split command. Puzzled. Any suggestions would be great. Code is below.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Public Structure ScavRecord
        Public latitude As String
        Public longitude As String
        Public message As String
        Public encrypted As String
    End Structure

    Dim Scav(4) As ScavRecord
    Dim nextScav As Integer

    Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click

        Dim read As New StreamReader("F:\Higher Computing Science\Assignment\files for candidates\messages.txt")
        nextScav = 0
        Do
            Dim temp As String = read.ReadLine()
            Dim seperated As String() = temp.Split(",")


            Scav(nextScav).latitude = seperated(0)
            Scav(nextScav).longitude = seperated(1)
            Scav(nextScav).message = seperated(2)
            nextScav = nextScav + 1
            ListBox.Items.Add(Scav(nextScav).latitude)
            ListBox.Items.Add(Scav(nextScav).longitude)
            ListBox.Items.Add(Scav(nextScav).message)

        Loop Until read.EndOfStream()


    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Will not fill how? Do you get empty records? An error?

Comment: the structure returns empty

Comment: Are they actually teaching with arrays and structures?

Comment: yeah, is that not the best method? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structures are *value types*, meaning that when you obtain a value of a structure type from somewhere, you’re getting a copy. That includes accessing an item in an array of value types, like you’re doing with `Scav(nextScav)`. So this line:

```
Scav(nextScav).latitude = seperated(0)
```

starts by evaluating `Scav(nextScav)` and giving you a copy of the `ScavRecord` at `nextScav`. Then you assign a value to its `latitude`. Then the copy is thrown away.

To fix this, you’ll need to assign the entire value:

```
Dim record As New ScavRecord()
record.latitude = separated(0)
record.longitude = separated(1)
record.message = separated(2)

Scav(nextScav) = record
```